# Is there a cheap way to test for mold spores?

Tags: mold, testing

We had toxic mold during the wintertime, which has been removed, by replacing the affected Sheetrock. However, my wife has often still the same symptoms she had at the time. Getting a contractor with the proper equipment out is very expensive. Are there any other cheap "household" tricks to be able to make at least a non-scientific test?

Comment: Doesn't really apply to you, since you already knew about it, but remember, mold is the new lead paint.  If you find you do have toxic mold, you'll have to disclose it when you sell.  And you can bet the buyers are going to want you to pay the 50k to have the guys with the moon suits come in, gut the drywall and framing, and basicly rebuild the house from scratch.

Comment: I am renting, so it is the problem of the property company :)

Comment: @txwinkinger - have you talked to your landlord about it?  It's a big potential liability concern for them, so I'd be surprised if they didn't at least investigate a bit (saying this as a former landlord myself).

Comment: @Eric: Yes, they played slumlords and did not even want to do anything when the mold was visible on the wall. We had to get the city bylaw enforcement involved to get them do anything. I also think they are not honest in disclosures. Well, that is real estate for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon carries [home mold tests](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BQY8B0). I have no idea if these are any good, but they are pretty inexpensive:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of the test kits. I recently had some mold issues and used a mail-in tape sample to test for mold. I did 8 samples for $50. I think 3 or 4 samples can also be done for lesser price.

Here is the site I used: http://www.mold-control-on-a-budget.com/ (I'm not associated in any way to her but can vouch for her service and professionalism after using the tape sample service.)